# All unbounded metric spaces are not compact. (Proof Verification)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I am having a difficult time explaining the result. I feel like the end of my proof is obvious, but I cant explain it. Here is what I wrote.

Let $X$ be an unbounded metric space and assume towards a contradiction that $X$ is compact. Assume $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathscr{U}$. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is finite, assume it has cardinality $n$. Observe that for each open set $U\in \mathscr{F}$, $U=B_{\epsilon}(x)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and for some $x\in X$.We claim that for all $x,y\in X$, that $d(x,y)<\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i$. So assume $x,y\in X$. If $x,y$ both lie in the same open set in $\mathscr{F}$, then clearly $d(x,y)<\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i$, which in turn contradicts the fact that $X$ is unbounded, and proving the result. So assume $x_1\in B_{\epsilon_1}(y_1)$ and $x_2\in B_{\epsilon_2}(y_2)$, where $y_1,y_2\in X$ and $B_{\epsilon_1}(y_1)\in \mathscr{F}$ and $B_{\epsilon_2}(y_2)\in\mathscr{F}$. Now, for every $U\in\mathscr{F}$, choose some point within each set. For clarity, we would choose $x_1\in B_{\epsilon_1}(y_1)$, and $x_2\in B_{\epsilon_2}(y_2)$ \dots $x_n\in B_{\epsilon_n}(y_n)$. Then we necessarily have, $d(x,z)<d(x_1,y_1)+d(x_2,y_2)+\dots+d(x_n,y_n)$ which is less than $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i$. Thus we have a bound on the distance between all points contradicting the fact that the metric space is unbounded.

Comment: Why do you claim $U$ is an open ball?

Comment: Note, your plan of action is wrong from the start. Every metric space $X$ has a finite open cover, namely $\{X\}$, so you can't hope to get a contradiction merely by assuming the existence of a finite open cover.

Comment: The definition I have for a subcover, is a sub collection of open sets of where the union of all the subsets in the collection is the whole space.

Comment: But won't a non trivial open cover be suffice?

Comment: As the example $\{X\}$ shows, it's not possible to prove that for _every_ open cover, there is no finite subcover. Instead show, assuming $X$ is unbounded, that there is _some_ open cover which has no finite subcover.

Comment: @quasi Thank you for the hint. I assumed $V$ is a finite sub cover of $S$ with cardinality $n$. Then $\forall x,y\in X$, we have $d(x,y)<n$, contradicting the fact that the metric space is unbounded. Now I just want to point out, I was visually doing the same thing as you. Unfortunately I wasnt as clever as you to think of that easy hint. Is there anyway to salvage my "proof", because it seems like the same idea.

Comment: To salvage your proof, start with the open cover as defined in my answer, then use the reasoning in your proof attempt to derive a contradiction. The main point is to get a contradiction, you can't just start with any old open cover. Using the set of all open balls with a fixed radius (centered at each point of the space), you get an open cover which can't have a finite subcover (since the space is unbounded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way: $X\ne \phi$ else $\{d(x,y):x,y\in X\}=\phi$ is a bounded set. So take any $x\in X.$ The cover $C=\{B_d(x,n):n\in \Bbb N\}$ has no finite sub-cover $D .$

Because  if $D$  is a finite  sub-cover of $ C$  then $X =\cup D=B_d(x,n)$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$ But then $\forall y,z\in X\;(d(y,z)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,y)<2n)$ contrary to $d$ being unbounded.

Comment: Edit after Acceptance: In the last line I had a typo: $\forall y,z\in X\,(d(y,x)....$ Changed  to $\forall y,z\in X\,(d(y,z).....$

Comment: The converse theorem is that if $(X,d)$ is a non-compact metric space then there exists an unbounded metric $e$ on X that is equivalent to $d $ (I.e. $d$ and $e $ generate the same topology.)

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Assume $X$ is unbounded.

Let $S = \{B(x,1)\mid x \in X\}$.

Then $S$ is an open cover.

Suppose there is a finite subcover.

Use the unboundedness of $X$ to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Prove the contrapositive instead: if $X$ is compact, then it's bounded. Assume $X$ is compact. If $X = \emptyset$, there is nothing to prove, so let $x_0 \in X$.  Consider the family of open balls $\mathscr U = \{B(x_0, n) : n = 1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Show that $\mathscr U$ is an open cover.  You take it from here...

By the way, in your attempt, you violated the first rule of proof writing, which is every symbol must be explained at the point where it is introduced. You don't say what your $\mathscr U$ is.  Assuming your $\mathscr U$  consists of one ball of some radius about each point of $X$, your proof is (with some editing) basically correct. But no one here understood it, because you didn't say what $\mathscr U$ is.

Edit: Again, regarding your original attempt, you should get rid of the variables $\epsilon_i$ by just taking all radii to be $1$.  Then you will end up with a finite open cover consisting of a finite number of balls of radius 1, $B(x_i, 1)$.   Now the diameter (max distance between points) in $X$ does *not* just depend on the number of balls but also on the distances between the centers.  Let $R$ be the max of $d(x_i, x_j)$ as $i, j$ vary. Then show for all $x, y \in X$, $d(x, y) <  R + 2$.

Comment: I think I can prove the statement after your great hint as well! Thank you fredgoodman. And yes that was a poor mistake, I should have introduced $\mathscr{U}$. In my "proof" $\mathscr{U}$ was an open cover. Where each open set in $\mathscr{U}$ is ball of radius epsilon around an arbitrary point, where the epsilons may vary.

Comment: Note addition to my answer.  Now you have two different proofs.